# trying to create a linked list using a function that takes a struct and sets the value

Tags: c++, struct, singly-linked-list

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
```

the structure

```
struct intnode { int value;
struct intnode *next; };
typedef struct intnode IntNode;
```

the code used to create a new node and set the new value

```
IntNode *intnode_construct(int value, IntNode *next) {
IntNode *p = (IntNode*)malloc(sizeof(IntNode));

assert (p != NULL);
p->value=value;
p->next = next;
return p;
}



    int main(int argc, const char * argv[]){


        IntNode *head1=NULL;
        IntNode *head2=NULL;
        IntNode *cur= NULL;

    head1 = intnode_construct(1, cur);
```

the values should be 1,3,5,7

```
for(int i=1;i<10;(i=i+2))
        {

        cur = intnode_construct(i, cur);


        }
        cur=head1;
```

printing the function

as soon as I run the program it gives me a runtime error

```
        do{
        cout<<cur->value<<endl;
            cur=cur->next;
        }
        while(cur->next != NULL);
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Except `#include <iostream>
using namespace std;`, How it is C++ and not C?

Comment: Use `new` in a C++ program, not `malloc`.  Also that `typedef struct` stuff is a tell-tale sign you're using / reading `C` material instead of `C++`.

Comment: C++ already has two linked lists in the standard library: [std::list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list) and [std::forward_list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/forward_list). Don't reinvent the wheel and create yet another version of this horrible, badly performing, data structure.

Comment: unfortunately using a new is not an option as this is an assignment and for some reason the question has the function already written like that

Comment: Take a piece of paper and draw all the allocations. What does `cur` point to after construction, and what is `cur->next` when the do..while condition is checked? Or **just run your code in a debugger** and the solution will immediately become clear.

Comment: @JesperJuhl tried doing that last assignment and let me tell I did not get an A on it XD

my only problem right now is that it doesn't want to print the values... I think that has to do with the parameters of the function in the loop or me trying to reset the pointer back to the head and going through the list

Comment: @Botje I tried doing that and in my eyes it's fine and it should work I don't know why it doesn't 

tried the debugger and it was of no help

Comment: @Botje
the main use of cur is to work as a cursor that goes through the list to either create more nodes or to print existing ones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as a counterpoint to your statement that the debugger is no help, I put a breakpoint on the first iteration of the do-while loop.
Observe:

```
(lldb) b 38
Breakpoint 1: where = debuggerisnohelp`main + 126 at debuggerisnohelp.cpp:38:15, address = 0x0000000100000cae
(lldb) r
Process 4631 launched: '/tmp/debuggerisnohelp' (x86_64)
Process 4631 stopped
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = breakpoint 1.1
    frame #0: 0x0000000100000cae debuggerisnohelp`main(argc=1, argv=0x00007ffeefbff708) at debuggerisnohelp.cpp:38:15
   35           cur=head1;
   36   
   37                   do{
-> 38           cout<<cur->value<<endl;
   39               cur=cur->next;
   40           }
   41           while(cur->next != NULL);
Target 0: (debuggerisnohelp) stopped.
(lldb) p *cur
(IntNode) $0 = {
  value = 1
  next = 0x0000000000000000
}
```

Note that `cur->next` is already `NULL` on the very first iteration!
Which means that after `cur = cur->next`, `cur` must be NULL and `cur->next` will dereference a null pointer.

The root cause of course is your assignment `cur = head1`, which repoints your nice `1->3->5->7->9->NULL` linked list to `1->NULL`.

Comment: oh ok 
thank you so much, but how can I rewind cur back to print the rest of the list starting with the head up to the 9

Comment: Your construct function prepends an element to the linked list. cur already points to the start of the list, you just constructed it in reverse.